# Copy EAP to my sql database: using C# Addin

Tags: c#, mysql, enterprise-architect

I am using my sql database for enterprise architect.
I need to copy EAP to DBMS using C# addin.
I can do it through EA using "Project Transfer (File to DBMS)". But using C# addin, I am not able to transfer.

I tried using :

```
Repository.GetProjectInterface().ProjectTransfer(sourcePath,targetPath,logPath);
```

But according to EA user guide this transfers from EAP or DBMS to EAP.

How can I transfer EAP to DBMS using c# addin?

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got reply from sparx system support team : "Unfortunately this is not supported. The ProjectTransfer function only supports transfer to EAP, it intentionally does not allow transfer to DBMS repositories. This can only be done manually."